# Camera on Timer and Surface View?

Tags: java, android

I am wondering how I would go about adding an image preview screen much like snap chat.
Currently, I do have my take photo button working by using the following code.

I know about using a `Timer` to create a `Runnable`, but how would I do this to show a countdown say of ten seconds before the app takes pics?

Layout File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="@string/tap"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    imgFavorite = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            open();
        }
    });
}

public void open(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    imgFavorite.setImageBitmap(bp);
}
```

Comment: You need to implement your own camera, not using default intent.

Comment: most basic implementation can be found here http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html